# xpath with namespace

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to use xpath in php SimpleXML with an xml file, of which the following is a relevant fragment:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <!--  Created on 21-Mar-2012 10:30:46 
  --> 
- <message:Structure xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure" xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXStructure.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXMessage.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <Header xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message">
  <ID>none</ID> 
  <Test>false</Test> 
  <Truncated>false</Truncated> 
  <Prepared>2011-11-18T13:56:45</Prepared> 
- <Sender id="OECD">
  <Name xml:lang="en">Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development</Name> 
  <Name xml:lang="fr">Organisation de coopération et de développement économiques</Name> 
  </Sender>
  </Header>
- <message:CodeLists>
- <CodeList id="CL_MEI_OBS_STATUS" agencyID="OECD">
  <Name xml:lang="en">Observation Status</Name> 
  <Name xml:lang="fr">Statut d'observation</Name> 
- <Code value="B">
  <Description xml:lang="en">Break</Description> 
  <Description xml:lang="fr">Rupture</Description> 
  </Code>
etc. etc.
```

In my php code I have the following, which registers the namespace then uses xpath to obtain CodeLists:-
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('test','http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message');

$codelistspath = $xml->xpath('test:CodeLists');

I would like to be able to use xpath to go one level lower in the tree, i.e. to CodeList and thought the following would work:-

$codelistpath = $xml->xpath('test:CodeLists/CodeList');

But it just produces an empty array.  I can find no way of accessing anything else in the document with xpath. I have spent hours trying to solve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CodeList` elements belong to the *default namespace* inherited from the `<message:Structure>` element - the namespace whose URI is `http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure`.

You will need to register that with `registerXPathNamespace()` as well.

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure');
$codelistpath = $xml->xpath('test:CodeLists/default:CodeList');
```

Comment: This is absolutely right, I had not realised CodeList was in a different namespace.  I have altered my code as you suggest, and all is working now.  I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like registerXPathNamespace only works for the *next* xpath query (according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php))... so if you've run `$xml->xpath('test:CodeLists')` already, try registering the namespace again before running `$xml->xpath('test:CodeLists/CodeList')`.

Comment: The *next* really means *following*. The `xpath()` method can be called using the registered namespaces at any time after registering them.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, Jason.  As Salathe says, the problem was that CodeList was in the default namespace and not the test namespace.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sometimes when I'm not that familiar with the tools I just throw something out and see what sticks.